# How can I detect changes made on HTML canvas from django?

Tags: django, html, canvas

We want to detect if a user has clicked something on an HTML canvas. If the user clicks on an object present on the canvas the value of this object changes. The POST operation does not seem to work. All we want to do is get the value of the object when the user has clicked it and send it to django.

Comment: This should be done with Ajax. However your question is very generic and not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Please provide some code - what you have you tried? How looks your Ajax request etc.